# Matching pattern repeats for unknown times. How to replace each matched string?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, repeat, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have this string

```
mark:: string1, string2, string3
```

I want it to be

```
mark:: xxstring1xx, xxstring2xx, xxstring3xx
```

The point is, I don't know how many times the matched string repeated. Sometimes there are 10 strings in the line, sometimes there is none. So far I have come up with this matching pattern `mark:: ((.*)(, )+)*`, but I'm unable to find a way to substitute individual matched string.

If possible I would like to have this output:

```
mark:: xxstring1xx
mark:: xxstring2xx
mark:: xxstring3xx
```

But if it's not possible it's fine to have the one-line solution

Comment: Can you be specific about your favorite language or tool?

Comment: Any special reason this needs to be done with a regex? This seems to be easier with a "splt" and a loop of the programming language you are using.

Comment: I just use Notepad++/VScode, not any language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using snippets you can make use of their ability to use conditionals.

IF you can select the line first, this is quite easy.  Use this keybinding in your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "alt+w",            // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(mark::\\s*)|([^,]+)(, )?/$1${2:+xx}$2${2:+xx}$3/g}"
  }
}
```

The find is simple: `(mark::\\s*)|([^,]+)(, )?`

replace: `$1${2:+xx}$2${2:+xx}$3`
Capture group 1 followed by `xx` if there is a group 2 `${2:+xx}` : conditional, followed by group 2, followed by another conditional.

Demo:

[image: snippet demo 1]

---

If you have a bunch of these lines in a file and you want to transform them all at once, then follow these steps:

1. In the Find widget, Find: `(mark::\s*)(.*)$` with the regex option enabled.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all matches.
3. Trigger your snippet keybinding from above.

Demo:

[image: snippet transform demo 2]

---

For your other version with separate lines for each entry, use this in the keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+w",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    // single line version 
    // "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(mark::\\s*)|([^,]+)(, )?/$1${2:+xx}$2${2:+xx}$3/g}"
    
    // each on its own line
    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(mark::\\s*)|([^,]+)(, )?/${2:+mark:: }${2:+xx}$2${2:+xx}${3:+\n}/g}"
  }
}
```

[image: snippet demo 3]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|mark::\s*)([^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?)
```

And replace with `$1xx$2xx`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UMfme3/1). *Details*:

- `(\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|mark::\s*)` - Group 1 (`$1`):

  - `\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*` - end of the previous successful match and then a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `|` - or
  - `mark::\s*` - `mark::` and zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?)` - Group 2 (`$2`):

  - `[^\s,]` - a char other than whitespace and comma
  - `(?:[^,]*[^\s,])?` - an optional sequence of zero or more non-commas and then a char other than a whitespace and a comma.

In Visual Studio Code file search and replace feature, you can use a Rust regex compliant regex:

```
(mark::(?:\s*(?:,\s*)?xx\w*xx)*\s*(?:,\s*)?)([^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?)
```

Replace with the same `$1xx$2xx` replacement pattern. ***Caveat***: you need to hit the replace button as many times as there are matches.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UMfme3/2) showing the replacement stages.

Comment: I put this into VScode and it says invalid escape. Do you know why?

Comment: @Ooker Yes, because it is not compliant with neither ECMAScript nor Rust regex flavors. Where are you using it? In the Search and replace in files (magnifying glass) or in-document search and replace?

Comment: in all files (Ctrl+Shift+H). So VScode's regex is ECMAScript or Rust flavor?

Comment: So, you are using the "magnifying glass", and you cannot use the `(\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|mark::\s*)([^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?)` here because it is not compliant with Rust regex flavor. Use Notepad++ instead (Ctrl + Shift + F, and choose *Replace in Files*).

Comment: @Ooker I added a VSCode compliant solution.